# How to create a scheduled task in Windows that will detect if an application currently has a system tray (notification area) icon?

Tags: windows, windows-7, process, scheduled-tasks, notification-area

I want to create a Windows 7 (64-bit) scheduled task to determine if an application currently has a system tray (AKA notification area) icon.

The scheduled task can run a batch file, PowerShell script, a utility, or use any other technique that can accomplish this task as long as there are not too many prerequisites (e.g. a Java application that requires a JRE).

I'm good with solutions that will detect the application's system tray icon being actually visible or solutions that simply require it to exist but when it is hidden from view.  I can accommodate solutions that will work to accomplish either type of discovery.

The name of the application generating the system tray icon will always be the same, as will the name and location of its executable file.

How can this be accomplished?

---

Edit: I did find [systrayscancmd](http://exodusdev.com/products/windows-system-tray-scan-utility), which would allow me to do exactly what I want, but unfortunately is not compatible with 64-bit versions of Windows.

Comment: To the downvoter: A downvote without any explanation is not helpful.  If you're going to downvote, please have the courtesy to explain how the post can be improved.